# What is the theory behind Z3 Optimize maximum and minimum functionality?

Tags: z3, smt

I am writing to inquire the theory/algorithm behind the Z3 Optimize function, especially for its `maximum` and `minimum` function. This seems pretty magic to me. Is it somehow a binary search or so? How can it efficiently figure out the max/min value here..?

I tried to search for the source code of the related functions (e.g., the [`execute_min_max`](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/8566d88b992610060a6523f28272d3384a2f2471/src/opt/opt_context.cpp#L394) function), but without a deep understanding about the terms there, it does not make too much sense to me... Basically what does `lex` stand for here? It seems that somehow the solutions are maintained inside a stack.

Any suggestions or advices would be appreciated very much. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the whole answer, but I'd wager `lex` is short for `lexicographic`.

Comment: See publications on the topic like, **1.** *Nikolaj Bjorner and Anh-Dung Phan.* **νZ - Maximal Satisfaction with Z3.** In Proc International Symposium on Symbolic Computation in Software Science, Gammart, Tunisia, December 2014. EasyChair Proceedings in Computing (EPiC). http://www.easychair.org/publications/?page=862275542
**2.** *Nicolaj Bjorner, Anh-Dung Phan, and Lars Fleckenstein.* **Z3 - An Optimizing SMT Solver.** In Proc. TACAS, volume 9035 of LNCS. Springer, 2015 **--** And, if those are not enough, any other publication related to the topic of **Optimization Modulo Theories**.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin That should be an answer, not a comment! Spot on.

Comment: @LeventErkok I thank you for the suggestion, but the question seems to be a bit unclear and too broad for me to answer, as it inadvertently ask for details concerning many topics. I am also the least knowledgeable person on the internal details of `z3` here, so I always try to keep my level of intrusion at minimum. If you think that the question is salvageable and can be given a proper answer, please don't be concerned about my half-assed suggestion in the comments feed, and proceed head on. I'll be happy to up-vote it, as always. (:

Comment: @patrick-trentin Your link to Bjorner and Phan didn't work for me, but this appears to be the paper: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/nbjorner-scss2014.pdf.  Here's a link to the second paper as well: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/nbjorner-scss2014.pdf.  The papers seem to overlap a bit, and if I had to choose one I'd choose the first one.

Comment: @MatthewWoodruff thank you very much, I'll update my  database of bibliographic references accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much for the kind notes. I appreciate it a lot. Would anyone post a answer here so I can credit accordingly?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin Please turn your comment into an answer! (You misspelled Nikolaj's name in the second reference, just FYI.)

Comment: @LeventErkok thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See publications on the topic like, e.g.

**1.** *Nikolaj Bjorner and Anh-Dung Phan.* **νZ - Maximal Satisfaction with Z3.** In Proc International Symposium on Symbolic Computation in Software Science, Gammart, Tunisia, December 2014. EasyChair Proceedings in Computing (EPiC). [[PDF]](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/nbjorner-scss2014.pdf)

**2.** *Nikolaj Bjorner, Anh-Dung Phan, and Lars Fleckenstein.* **Z3 - An Optimizing SMT Solver.** In Proc. TACAS, volume 9035 of LNCS. Springer, 2015 -- And, if those are not enough, any other publication related to the topic of Optimization Modulo Theories. [[Springer]](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-46681-0_14) [[[PDF]](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/nbjorner-nuz.pdf)

---

The `z3` Optimization Modulo Theories (OMT) solver has various optimization procedures. Some of these techniques are more efficient than others, but can only deal with certain classes of objective functions (i.e. *Pseudo-Boolean/MaxSMT objectives*). In the case of *Linear Arithmetic* cost functions which cannot be reduced to *Pseudo-Boolean/MaxSMT*, the basic approach for the optimization search, adopted by most OMT solvers, is to run either in *linear-* or *binary-search*. For a comparison among the two approaches, see either

- *Roberto Sebastiani and Silvia Tomasi* **Optimization in SMT with LA(Q) Cost Functions.** In IJCAR, volume 7364 of LNAI, pages 484–498. Springer, July 2012. [[PDF]](http://disi.unitn.it/~rseba/papers/ijcar12.pdf)
- *Roberto Sebastiani and Silvia Tomasi*. **Optimization Modulo Theories with Linear Rational Costs.** ACM Transactions on Computational Logics, 16(2), March 2015. [[PDF]](http://disi.unitn.it/~rseba/papers/a12-sebastiani.pdf)

I am not sure how to answer the question *"How can it **efficiently** figure out the max/min value here..?"*, because first one should define what **efficiency** means in this context. As you can read from the previous two publications, *binary-search* is not always the best choice because search steps in optimization don't have all the same *"cost"*.

The definition of *lexicographic* optimization is readily available all over the internet, this is the one I used very recently:

> **Definition 4.6.4. (Lexicographic OMT [BP14, BPF15, ST15b, ST15c]).** Let `<φ,O>` be a multi-objective OMT problem, where `φ` is a ground SMT formula and `O = { obj_1 , ..., obj_N }` is a sorted list of `N` objective functions. We call **Lexicographic OMT problem**, the problem of finding the model `M` which satisfies `φ` and makes each `obj_i` minimum¹ in decreasing order of priority.
>
> *¹: in practice objectives need not to be all minimized, this is just for ease of definition*

*AFAIK*, the lexicographic optimization procedure implemented in `z3` is not extensively described in any publicly available paper. However, a trivial approach for `lex` is to run `N` single-objective (incremental) optimizations, each time fixing the optimum value obtained at the previous round.

---

If this is not enough to answer your questions, please take a look to any other publication related to the topic of **Optimization Modulo Theories**.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for the extra references, in particular.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much for this great answer!